# java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, oracle11g

I'm working on Struts 2 Framework with Hibernate 3.3 and using Oracle 11g. My web project was working fine since 5 months. But recently I'm facing the java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection during some idle time. I'll explain the scenario follows..
My hibernate.cfg.xml configuration is

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">
        thread
    </propert
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl</property>
<property name="connection.username">user</property>
<property name="connection.password">user</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">
        oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    </property>
<property name="myeclipse.connection.profile">Oracle</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
<property name="dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect </property>
```

And my HibernateSessionFactory conf is

```
private static String CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION = "/hibernate.cfg.xml";
private static final ThreadLocal<Session> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<Session>();
private static Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
private static org.hibernate.SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static String configFile = CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION;
static {
    try {
        configuration.configure(configFile);
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err
                .println("%%%% Error Creating SessionFactory %%%%");
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private HibernateSessionFactory() {
}
public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
    Session session = (Session) threadLocal.get();

    if (session == null || !session.isOpen()) {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            rebuildSessionFactory();
        }
        session = (sessionFactory != null) ? sessionFactory.openSession()
                : null;
        threadLocal.set(session);
    }

    return session;
}
public static void rebuildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        configuration.configure(configFile);
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err
                .println("%%%% Error Creating SessionFactory %%%%");
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void closeSession() throws HibernateException {
    Session session = (Session) threadLocal.get();
    threadLocal.set(null);

    if (session != null) {
        session.close();
    }
}
public static org.hibernate.SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
public static void setConfigFile(String configFile) {
    HibernateSessionFactory.configFile = configFile;
    sessionFactory = null;
}
public static Configuration getConfiguration() {
    return configuration;
}
```

Then the error comes when the following code runs

```
session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
Query query = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
try {
                // session.connection().close();
                System.out.println("CLOSED :"
                        + session.connection().isClosed());
                if (session.connection().isClosed()) {
                    System.out.println("RECONNECTING.......");
                    session.reconnect();
                }
                System.out.println("CLOSED :"
                        + session.connection().isClosed());
            } catch (Exception e1) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
try {
for (Iterator it = query.iterate(); it.hasNext();) {
                    chk = true;
                    ur = (EmagEnterpriseLogin) it.next();
} catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

When the above snippet runs even though able to session was opened and created query successfully, But fails at Iterating query. First time comes as

```
Caused By:java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
```

But before this error in first try i captured the session.Connection.isClosed() was false. But after first error then keeps on coming as SQL State=null and from second time i could get session.Connection.isClosed() was true. And then reconnecting executes but still the same error repeats.I also tried rebuilding sessionfactory, that too failed. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What is the oracle error?

Comment: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query using iterate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the solution for my problem is using third party Connection Provider instead of using Hibernate Native connection provider. I used c3p0 Connection provider , that also given me some problems and i solved that too. The reference link for c3p0 is here.. [Hibernate c3p0 Connection NewPooledConnection close Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847279/hibernate-c3p0-connection-newpooledconnection-close-exception)